# ChromeDriver timing out when deployed (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, websphere, selenium-chromedriver

I am having trouble getting the ChromeDriver started for Selenium when my application is deployed. It is a Liberty application with WebSphere Application Server on Bluemix.

The application is working just fine when using a test driver, and on my local instances of WAS. When running the application on Bluemix I keep getting the errors

```
Error 500: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z' System info: host: 'ab262009-655a-4b7e-72a8-eb5250d668ac', ip: '10.254.1.142', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-75-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_161' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

My logs are showing these two errors

```
[err] /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: 1: /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
APP/0[ERROR ] org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process 
exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
APP/0org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
APP/0[ERROR ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable:192'
APP/0Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:31300/status] to be available after 20018 ms
```

or

```
/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Source Code:

```
public static void runTest(String os) throws InterruptedException {

    // Detect Operating System user is running
    System.out.println("Operating system read in: " + os);
    // Initialize driver

    if (os.contains("Mac")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/chromedriver");
    } else {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/chromedriver_windows.exe");
    }
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Error is thrown on the ChromeDriver object creation line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting up your binary location, before the WebDriver object creation. Update your runTest method as per below and then try out.

```
public static void runTest(String os) throws InterruptedException {

    // Detect Operating System user is running
    System.out.println("Operating system read in: " + os);
    // Initialize driver
    String DRIVER_BINARY_LOCATION;
    switch(os.toUpperCase()){

        case "MAC":
            DRIVER_BINARY_LOCATION = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/chromedriver");
            break;
        case "LINUX":
            DRIVER_BINARY_LOCATION = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/chromedriver");
            break;
        case "WINDOW":
            DRIVER_BINARY_LOCATION = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/chromedriver.exe");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Any meaningful message");
    }
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DRIVER_BINARY_LOCATION);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seeing the same timeout error in the browser and the log is showing me
    [err] /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: 1: /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: Sorry I pasted the code in wrong originally. I updated what I originally had. Erased some extra stuff copying it on here.

Comment: Can you please let me know that where have you placed your Chrome driver binaries and what OS you are using?

Comment: It is in the root directory of the server's package in the resources folder. I'm on Mac OS, the server itself is Linux.

Comment: Below are the list of combination of WebDriver binaries and OS
* Linux -> Linux ChromeDriver Binary
* MAC -> MAC ChromeDriver Binary
* Windows -> Window ChromeDriver Binary
So just check for the correct binaries. As in your code in the `if-else` block, you are only checking for `MAC` os for the `other OS` like Windows/Linux, it always picks the windows chrome driver binary. So if your tests are running in Linux machine, your code selects the binary of Windows machine. Please check my updated answer above.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot and retest. But the os string that is passed, is read in from the browser of the person viewing the website, not the actual machine. So it was reading Mac (I am on a Mac) and I manually replaced the Mac driver with Linux just to see if it would work and I don't believe it did. I'll rewrite the code to accommodate all operating systems though just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[err] /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: 1: /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

...implies that the line `System.setProperty()` is having a **Syntax error** specifically a **Unterminated quoted string**

Your main issue is within the `System.setProperty()` with the **path.separator** as follows :

### Solution

Change the `System.setProperty()` line as follows :

```
if (os.contains("Mac")) {
    String user_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", user_dir+"/resources/chromedriver");
    } else {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", user_dir+"/resources/chromedriver_windows.exe");
```

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the same error you can try the following alternative :

```
if (os.contains("Mac")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/chromedriver");
    } else {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/chromedriver_windows.exe");
```

Comment: Unfortunately seeing the same issue :(

Comment: @user3413540 Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Still have the same issue. It sounds based off the error I see in browser it has no issue finding the driver file, just the new ChromeDriver() line is giving it trouble and it won't start. I'm using the Mac driver on my machine which works fine, the server appears to be running Linux. I have tried both Linux and Mac drivers when deploying.

Comment: @user3413540 In that case the _log message_ `[err] /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: 1: /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/projectname/resources/chromedriver: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` shouldn't have been there

Comment: The reason why I say that, because when I change the directory to a place where the driver is not located, it gives another error saying it can't find it. In the stack trace line 33 is the Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver() line. This is a little further down the stack trace:

APP/0 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
APP/0Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
APP/0Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
APP/0 at com.ibm.esh.o2c.art.Tester.runTest(Tester.java:33)